# Separating Hyperpanes - The Elements of Statistical Learning

Tags: svm

[image]

The authors say that the green line depicts a hyperplane or affine set $L$ defined by the equation $f(x) = \beta_0+\beta^Tx = 0$; since we are in $R^2$ this is a line. One property is:

For any two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ lying in $L$, $\beta^T(x_1-x_2)=0$, and hence $\beta^*=\beta/ \lVert \beta \rVert$ is the vector normal to the surface of $L$.

I understand $\beta^T(x_1-x_2)=0$ but how $\beta^*=\beta/ \lVert \beta \rVert$ is derived?

Comment: What does it mean to you that a vector is orthogonal to the surface on an affine space L? For sure we could try to say that a vector $y$ is orthogonal to $L$ if $\langle y, x \rangle = 0$ for all $x$ lying in $L$. However, if the line is an affine one then this is geometrically not what one wants because then $y$ is orthogonal to the vectors pointing from $0$ into the line $L$. What becomes clear then is that those things lying exactly within the green line in the picture above (up to moving them around in the space which is irrelevant if we want to say 'orthogonal to all of them') ...

Comment: is actually all differences $x_1 - x_2$ where $x_1, x_2$ are both in $L$, hence, we want to be orthogonal on them. The equation before states exactly that: $\langle \beta, d \rangle = 0$ for all difference vectors $d = x_1 - x_2$...